# How to find data type in C++17 any vector?

Tags: c++, c++17, stdvector, stdany

I am trying to find the data type of an element of a vector of any type.

I tried the following code:

```
#include <any>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<any> myList;

    myList.push_back(std::string("Hello"));
    myList.push_back(3);
    myList.push_back(true);

    std::any t1 = "Hello";
    std::any t2 = 3;
    std::any t3 = true;
    std::cout<<t1.type().name()<<endl;
    std::cout<<t2.type().name()<<endl;
    std::cout<<t3.type().name()<<endl;
    std::cout<<myList[0].type().name()<<endl;
    std::cout<<myList[1].type().name()<<endl;
    std::cout<<myList[2].type().name()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
PKc
i
b
NSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
i
b
```

As you can see the `int` and `bool` are correctly identified, but the string type returns something else. Also, this happens with all the complex C++ data structures as well such as vectors and maps. Is there any way to detect the specific data type?

My ultimate aim is to implement a custom vector data type such as a `list` in python. with basic push and get functions.

Comment: Don't include bits/stdc++.h, it's just always wrong. If you see a tutorial using this, you know immediately that it's a bad tutorial (which may be the only valid use of that non-standard header)

Comment: `t1` holds a `const char*`, not a `std::string`.  It makes sense that the type name is different.

Comment: `The "any" here refers to the "std::any".` Don't take the whole std namespace into your program with those god awful practices and you don't have to explain that to anyone.

Comment: Why do you think the std::string typename is wrong? Have you tried demangling these names?

Comment: FYI `type().name()` should only be used for logging. [std::type_info::name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name) `[…]Returns an implementation defined null-terminated character string containing the name of the type. No guarantees are given; in particular, the returned string can be identical for several types and change between invocations of the same program.[…]`

Comment: Taking c++ and trying to make it work like python seems like a bad way to learn the language. Languages are different for a reason, they have strengths and weaknesses. Learn the differences and how to utilize them instead of trying to make the language work the way you want it to.

Comment: `but the string type returns something else` no, it clearly returns an implementation defined character string for `std::string`. Did you check what `typeof(std::string).name()` returns?

Comment: Change `std::any t1 = "Hello";` to `std::any t1 = std::string("Hello");`.  In C++, a C-style string literal is a different type from a std::string.  There is also `"Hello"s` which will make a std::string literal.